# Why does the Sentinel-2 Surface Reflectance product in GEE begin on March 28, 2017?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction

I'm trying to figure out why the GEE Sentinel-2 Surface Reflectance product is available since March 28, 2017 (as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR#terms-of-use) in Dataset Availability).

Is this date significant?

Is it possible to obtain Surface Reflectance data in GEE before this date without needing to do my own atmospheric correction?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Chit chat like greetings, statements of appreciation/thanks, etc should not be included in your posts here - see [help/behavior].  I suspect that this may be something for Google to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESA hasn't yet produced/processed level-2 data before that date.  You currently have to process your own.  You might be able to do this within Earth Engine and avoid having to download/upload your own copy of the dasta using [SIAC](https://github.com/MarcYin/SIAC)

Comment: Great, thanks so much!